# Images are blurred

Tags: html, css

Can someone also help me fix the images here? : http://www.howtoplaystation.com/2019/07/blog-post.html at the bottom( in the “YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE” tab)? They are all blurred and resized. I can only add CSS, not change them. Thank you

```
.related-posts .related-thumb img {width: 100%;height: 100%;display: block }.related-posts .related-thumb:after {content: '';display: block;position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 10;top: 0;left: 0;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);transition: background .3s }.related-posts .related-thumb:hover:after {background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.1) }.related-posts .ty-entry {padding: 8px 10px 0 0;width: 100%;line-height: 1.2em;box-sizing: border-box;z-index: 2 }
```

Comment: Like this remove `width: 100%;height: 100%;` or change 
`a.related-thumb img { width:72px }`

Comment: They are blurred because the images are too small for their containers.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: your blog page is making the img thumb size: 140x140 px. its size is too small so that it's being blurred.

Comment: So can you guys please tell me what I should add in the CSS to fix the problem? I added .related-posts .related-thumb img { width:72px } but now they look completely weird. Take a look here:https://www.howtoplaystation.com/2019/07/blog-post.html @mplungjan

Comment: Ok add height 72 too

Comment: Or rescan in bigger size and keep 100x100%

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for your help. I added height 72 too and now it still looks weird, see: https://www.howtoplaystation.com/2019/07/blog-post.html The images are small and cropped. Can you help me with that?

Comment: The problem is with the thumb image itself not the css code .. just increase thumb image size ..make it something like 250*250 minimum

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Can you please tell me how I can do that? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: How is your site built with ? Is it blogger ?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet sorry for the late answer. Yes, it is Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are too small. When you set their sizes to 100%, they are enlarged to fit the entire box. You also don't wanna set the size of the images to 72x72, because you want each image to fill the entire box that contains it. 
So, you should get images with a bigger size, and you can set their sizes to 100% then.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get images with a bigger size? And where should I add these images? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I usually look for websites to download images for free. You can replace the img src in your html code with the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can't I just edit my own pictures in Photoshop? What should be then the height and weight?

Comment: You will have the same problem with Photoshop, since you need to enlarge the images, so they will be blurry. But if you wanna resize your images to a smaller size, you can use Photoshop. Like Kareem suggested, 250x250 should be a good size.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with Photoshop, but I still didn't manage to fix the blurred images. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Converting a 72 by 72px image to 250 by 250px will be blurry. Photoshop will not be able to fix that. You can use Photoshop IF you wanna resize your image to a smaller size which is not the case here. Try to look for larger images that are 250x250 px in size.

Comment: I actually used the original picture from my pc( which is very big) and made it 250x250px, see: https://snag.gy/lCMtn3.jpg But it still didn't fix the issue.